# Exception Error C++ //Visual Studio

Tags: c++

So im creating an engine from scrath(learnign purposes).
And when i test my **TArray** i get an Execption thrown in my **Memory.h** file. This happens only when im trying to test the **TArray**

Here is my code for **TArray.h**

```
     #pragma once
     #include "Memory/DynamicLinearStackAllocator.h"

    template <typename T, typename Allocator =  DynamicLinearStackAllocator>
    class TArray
  {
 private:
  Allocator m_Allocator;
  uint32 m_ElementCount;
public:

FORCEINLINE TArray()
{
}

FORCEINLINE ~TArray()
{
    m_Allocator.Destroy();
}

FORCEINLINE TArray(const uint32 InElementCount)
{
    m_Allocator.Resize<T>(InElementCount, m_ElementCount);
    m_ElementCount = InElementCount;
}

FORCEINLINE void Add(const T &InValue)
{
}

FORCEINLINE T* GetData() const { return m_Allocator.GetAllocator<T>(); }

FORCEINLINE uint32 Num() const
{
    return m_ElementCount;
}

FORCEINLINE T& operator[](uint32 InElementIndex) const
{
    check(m_ElementCount > InElementIndex);
    return GetData()[InElementIndex];
}
};

namespace Tests
{
FORCEINLINE void TestArrays()
{
    {
        TArray<float> data(10);
        check(data.Num() == 10);

        for(uint32 i = 0; i < data.Num(); i++)
        {
            data[i] = 2.0f;
        }

        check(data[0] == 2.0f);
    }

    {
        TArray<uint32> data(5);
        data[0] = 10;
        data[1] = 5;
        check(data.Num() == 5);

        check(data[0] == 10);
        check(data[1] == 5);
    }

    {
        TArray<float> data(1);
        data[2] = 2.0f;
    }

}
}
```

When i try to compile(Im using Visual Studio 2017) it gives me an execption error at this position in **Memory.h**

```
    static void* Copy(void *InDestination, const void *InSource, size_t InSize)
{
    check_slow(InDestination);
    check_slow(InSource);
    check_slow(InSize > 0);

    return memcpy(InDestination, InSource, InSize);
}
```

The test is getting called in the main function with this code:

```
    int main()
{
    Tests::TestAssertion();
    Tests::TestMemory();
    Tests::TestAllocator();
    Tests::TestArrays();

    return 0;
}
```

my goal currently is to look if the logger shows me the error here:

```
    {
        TArray<float> data(1);
        data[2] = 2.0f;
    }
```

here is a screenshot of the full error https://gyazo.com/6c1d6779623ffea97504f5b23f9fd7da

edit: here is the code for the allocator

```
    #pragma once
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include "Core.h"

  #define MEMORY_ALIGMENT 16

  struct Memory
  {
     // TODO:Rework types.

     static void* Allocate(const int32 InCount, const size_t InSize)
     {
      check_slow(InCount > 0);
      check_slow(InSize > 0);

      const size_t size = InSize * InCount;
      return _aligned_malloc(size, MEMORY_ALIGMENT);
     }

     static void Free(void *InBlock)
    {
      check_slow(InBlock);
      _aligned_free(InBlock);
    }

     static void* Copy(void *InDestination, const void *InSource, size_t InSize)
 {
     check_slow(InDestination);
     check_slow(InSource);
     check_slow(InSize > 0);

     return memcpy(InDestination, InSource, InSize);
    }
   };

  void* operator new (size_t InSize)
 {
  return Memory::Allocate(1, InSize);
 }

 void operator delete (void* InBlock)
 {
  Memory::Free(InBlock);
 }


namespace Tests
{
   struct MemoryTestStruct
   {
      uint32 p0;
      uint32 p1;
      uint32 p2;
      uint32 p3;
  };

    FORCEINLINE void TestMemory()
   {
     MemoryTestStruct *t = new MemoryTestStruct();
     check(t);
     delete t;
 }
}
```

edit2: Here is the code for the StackAlloctor

```
    #pragma once
    #include "../Core.h"

    class DynamicLinearStackAllocator
     {
      private:
      void *m_Data;
      public:

template <typename T>
FORCEINLINE void Resize(const uint32 InElementCount, const uint32 InPreviousElementCount)
{
    void *temp = Memory::Allocate(InElementCount, sizeof(T));

    if (InPreviousElementCount > 0)
    {
        const SIZE_T size = sizeof(T) * InPreviousElementCount;

        Memory::Copy(temp, m_Data, size);

        Memory::Free(m_Data);
    }

    m_Data = temp;
}

template <typename T>
FORCEINLINE T* GetAllocator() const
{
    return (T*)m_Data;
}

 FORCEINLINE void Destroy()
 {
     Memory::Free(m_Data);
 }
};

namespace Tests
{
 FORCEINLINE void TestAllocator()
  {
     DynamicLinearStackAllocator alloc;
     alloc.Resize<float>(2, 0);
     alloc.Destroy();
  }
 }
```

Comment: First, don't post images.  Post the actual error here.  Second -- *So im creating an engine from scrath(learnign purposes).* -- One of the things that's included in learning how to write programs is learning how to debug your own programs.  Have you run your program, step-by-step, in the debugger and thus determine where the fault lies?

Comment: i tried but i just dont understand the error

Comment: The error is "Access Violation".  So you were not prepared or understand what this error means?  It is the Windows standard "your program is accessing a memory location that isn't valid" error message.

Comment: InSource was an invalid pointer for the memcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing the code for your Allocator, but the problem is probably this line in your `TArray` constructor:

```
m_Allocator.Resize<T>(InElementCount, m_ElementCount);
```

At this point, `m_ElementCount` has not been initialized and will have some random value in it.  `Resize` is then probably trying to free up memory that hasn't been allocated (because of the uninitialized value in `m_ElementCount`).  You should pass in a 0 for the second parameter of the `Resize` call in your constructor

```
m_Allocator.Resize<T>(InElementCount, 0);
```

since there is no existing allocated memory to free.

Also, your default constructor for `TArray` should initialize `m_Allocator.m_data` to `nullptr` (or add a default constructor to DynamicLinearStackAllocator to do that) and set `m_ElementCount` to 0.

Comment: i edited the answer with the allocator code

Comment: @kti You need to show DynamicLinearStackAllocator`, specifically the `Resize` function (and any other functions it calls).

Comment: got it. added it

Comment: @kti See my updated answer.